# VLC 2.2 and Levels

Tags: video, mp4, vlc, rtp, libvlc

I have an application I've written to provide simulated MP4 camera streams to a "black box". I use irony quotes because I don't have access to its sources, but we do have a support contract with the vendor who makes it.

This black box supports h.264 Level 2.2. It does not use anything like an SDP, but just expects the camera streams to be 640x480 @ 30hz. I understand this is reasonably standard output for surveillance cameras.

So my application is using vlc (libVlc to be specific) to stream MP4 files to this device. I have this working fine (with [one minor exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501242/looping-an-mp4-video), but that's a separate issue). However, that is with Vlc 2.1.5. When I tried upgrading to the latest 2.2.1, instead of the videos on the other side of our black box we are just seeing whiteish-gray squares.

Our vendor looked over wireshark dumps, and told me that the vlc 2.2.1 stream is reporting itself as [Level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Levels) 5.1 instead of 2.2, and that its now using [High Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles) instead of Baseline or Main. It almost looks like VLC is trying to "upgrade" (transcode?) my video on me, and that's messing up the reader on that black box.

Is there any way to get the old behavior from vlc 2.1.5 back, or force it to use the Level and Profile of my choosing?

Comment: That can't be right. 640x480 @ 30 fps is Level 3 not 2.2. The maximum fps for that resolution at 2.2 is ~16.85. Are all your source MP4 files at 640x480 @ 30 fps?

Comment: @aergistal - That's what the "Codec" tab of VLC's Current Media Information dialog tells me. The deliverable that came with them also says they are 640x480. The level...I'm not sure how I'd double-check that.

Comment: I just got a "popular question" badge for this 0-scored question. Shame there isn't some extra badge for that! I could hang it up next to all my "tumbleweed"s .

Answer (score 3):

**H.264 Profiles**

[Profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles) are sets of capabilities. If your black box only supports the `Baseline` profile it'll not be able to decode a stream using `High` capabilities.

In `VLC` you can set the H.264 profile to be used by the `x264` encoder like this:

`--sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{profile=baseline}...`

**H.264 Levels**

Think of levels as a constraint/indicator of required decoder performance. If a decoder supports a certain level for a certain profile then it must be able to decode streams at that level and any of the lower levels.

First of all, the level for 640x480 @ 30 fps is `3` and not `2.2`.

You can calculate this as following:

```
macrobolocks = ceil(640/16) * ceil(480/16) = 1200
macroblocks/s = macroblocks * 30 = 36000
```

The reason for `ceil` is that non-mod16 resolution are padded to a multiple of 16.

You then take a look at the [H.264 Levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Levels). You are within the frame size limit for `2.2` which is `1620` but the max decoding speed is greater than `20252` so you have to choose the next level wich is `3`. You'll also have to consider the maximum bitrate for the `Baseline` profile in that table.

If you have an Android device you can download my [H.264 Calculator app from the Amazon App Store](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013IF1H2I) (I can send you the `apk` if you don't like their Orwellian app permissions)

The `x264` encoder will automatically choose a level based on your encoding parameters. With `VLC` you can actually set the flag yourself using something like:

`--sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{profile=baseline,level=22}"...`

Beware, this sets the encoder output flag and doesn't actually produce a `Level 2.2` stream. You can put any values you want, so it's possible to mark a Full HD stream at 60 fps as `Level 2.2` even if it's nowhere the level limits.

**VLC Transcoding**

If you want to make sure you're sending a correct stream you'll need to transcode the source material. This is an example for 640x480 @ 30 fps which results in a `Level 3` H.264 stream like I showed you above. If you want `Level 2.2` you'll need to lower the resolution or framerate or both. Your video bitrate can go lower too in that case.

`cvlc input.mp4 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{profile=baseline},fps=30,width=640,height=480,vb=1372,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{...}`

**Mediainfo**

[Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) is a great tool to get information about a media file. You can check the specs of your input files, but it won't help you detect a wrong level which was forced into or wrongfully chosen by the encoder. The safest way is to re-encode.